# Build error when trying to instantiate a class in another module

Tags: android, android-build, android-module

I must be missing something pretty obvious, but I need to find an answer for this. I started to modularize my app, and this is the setup:

[image: setup]

The `:database` module should abstract the connection to the database. But when I remove the dependency of some-lib from the `:app` module, I get the following error:

```
error: cannot access ClassA
class file for com.some.lib.ClassA not found
```

How can I instantiate `ClassB` in my `:app` module without making it depend on `some-lib`?

Hopefully the question is clear enough.

Comment: You can expose `some-lib` as Api in your `database` gradle module.

Comment: @JeelVankhede The problem is that I don't want the `app` module to have access to classes of `some-lib`.